# watchOS AudioRecorder has no input, doesn't ask for permission

Tags: watchkit

I am using this code to show the AudioRecorder on the Apple Watch (taken from https://www.raywenderlich.com/345-audio-recording-in-watchos-tutorial)

```
let outputURL = chatMasterController.newOutputURL()
    let preset = WKAudioRecorderPreset.narrowBandSpeech
    let options: [String : Any] =
        [WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey: 30]


    presentAudioRecorderController(
        withOutputURL: outputURL,
        preset: preset,
        options: options) {
            [weak self] (didSave: Bool, error: Error?) in

            guard didSave else { return }
            print("finished audio to \(chatID) at \(outputURL)")

            print(outputURL)

       }
```

The Recorder pops up however it doesn't seem to take any input. The wave forms don't rise while speaking and trying to play the recording afterwards leaves me with 0.2seconds of silence no matter how long the recording is.

I've tried another app that's making use of the microphone and this app did ask me for permission to record audio. I have feared having dismissed the permission before so I have reinstalled my app which however didn't change anything - no permission being asked, no input being generated.

Is there something I've missed e.g. importing a lib?

Answer (score 1):

I've now figured it out. You don't just need the `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` string in your Watch app's plist - you also need to set it in the iPhone's plist.

Only setting it on the Watch does nothing, only setting it on the iPhone doesn't let you allow it on the Watch directly. So you need it on both.

No idea why this isn't documented anywhere but it fits Apple's "we are going downhill" movement :)